# checking payment date for my method update()

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

In my method update() I have to checking the `date_payment` and la `date_seance`. 
if the date_payment is greater than the date_seance, I must have an error message

My checking does not work ... I did a dump..

```
Training::find($id);
```

[image]

My dateFormat is null? It's perhaps the problem?

```
public function update(Request $request, $id)
{
    $request->validate([
        'date_seance' => 'required',
        'hour_start' => 'required',
        'hour_end' => 'required',
        'fk_motorbike' => 'required',
        'fk_former' => 'required',
        'fk_student' => 'required'
    ]);

    $date_seance = $request->get('date_seance');

    $hour_start = $request->get('hour_start');
    $hour_end = $request->get('hour_end');

    $fk_motorbike = $request->get('fk_motorbike');
    $fk_student = $request->get('fk_student');
    $fk_former = $request->get('fk_former');
    $fk_typeseance = $request->get('fk_typeseance');

    $datePayment = Payment::where('fk_student', $request->get('fk_student'))
        ->whereDate('date_payment', ">" , $date_seance)
        ->first();

    if(isset($datePayment)) {
        return redirect()->route('trainings.index')
            ->with('error', 'There is a problem with the payment date! ');
    } else {
        $trainings = Training::find($id);
        $trainings->date_seance = $request->get('date_seance');
        ...
        $trainings->save();

        return redirect()->route('trainings.index')
            ->with('success', 'Update!')->withInput();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Your Eloquent query looks okay.

You could try the following:

1. Inspect the $date_seance right before using it (is it filled out and
   in the right format?)
2. Changing `->first()` to `->toSql()` and
   dumping the result for easier debugging in a database client.

In these cases it is my experience that it is often a small error or misunderstanding of formats.

Answer (score 1):

Use `firstOrFail()` instead of `first()`.

Answer (score 0):

I have found my erreur it was the cache pfffffff... :-(

```
php artisan config:cache
php artisan cache:clear
php artisan view:clear
```

It woks now ! Thank you for your help.